# VB script insert data in to another worksheet using values of ADODB record set

Tags: excel, vba

I have to insert data from one worksheet to another using VB Scripts ADODB model.
As of now i have queried the excel and have obtained the record set containing the values with multiple rows.
I have to insert these values into a blank worksheet say Sheet3 beginning with the top most row.
Please help me find any methods for achieving the same as i am very new to excel vba

```
Exceldb = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\VAS_AUTOMATION_v1.1\Book1.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
Dim sDBConnectionString, i, iCol

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
sDBConnectionString = Exceldb
con.ConnectionString = sDBConnectionString
con.Open

strQuery = "select * from [Sheet1$] where TEST_CASE_ID in ("'testcase_name'"))"

Set strRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Dim objCmd 'As New ADODB.Command
Set objCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objCmd.ActiveConnection = con
objCmd.CommandType = 1
objCmd.CommandText = strQuery
Set strRecordSet = objCmd.Execute
con.Close
```

Comment: Activate the destination/target sheet, and set up a loop to traverse the records you've collected. Set the value property of each cell in each row to the corresponding value in the current data record, and repeat that process until you're out of records. You can access a cell via the Cells(row, col) syntax, and assign the value through the .Value property. Use that as a starting point and go from there.

Comment: Using the above code how would I access the specific sheet. Are there any methods like sheet(sheet).cells(row)

Comment: You can use the Activate method of the Worksheet object, passing in the desired sheet name. You can then reference that sheet with ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1), ActiveSheet.Cells(1,2) (for example). There are several different ways you can accomplish this; I'm merely illustrating one approach.